# How to install .deb package with double click

Tags: apt, package-management, deb, gdebi

I'd like to install .deb packages I download from the internet, (ie google chrome or discord) from nautilus by just double clicking (the way it works in windows). I used to use gdebi, but it opens a gui panel, which annoys me personally so I removed it. Is there any way to do this by shell script or install some package that does it for me?

To be clear, I have root access on my machine, I can change arbitrary files and can run any scripts as "sudo." I just want to be able to install .deb packages in nautilus by double-clicking, instead of having to open a terminal.

I realize the security implications of this, but I only download packages I trust and have nothing valuable on my computer so I would like a way to save the 30 seconds.

Comment: I think you should keep in mind one difference between Windows and Ubuntu.  With Windows, if you're able to install it "just by double clicking", most likely you have a system administrator's account.  With Ubuntu, you have a normal account and you gain administrator's privilege by using `sudo` with your password.  You never log into a Linux system with administrator's access already "on".  Thus, with Linux, it's expected you'll need a few more steps compared to Windows.

Comment: Could I add a shell script with admin privileges that listens for my clicks in nautilus and runs dpkg -i <packagename> and then sudo apt -f though?

Comment: You're asking to bypass the authentication stage for `sudo`, but Linux is a multi-user system.  Windows originally (and, in a way, still is) a single-user system -- it can assume whoever logs in is an admin, by default.  So, I would say "no", but perhaps someone else knows more than me and can help you with this.  I think it's better to understand that Linux and Windows are different, instead of trying to force one to "emulate" the other.

Comment: That's not needed, I can run sudo on the script just fine. Since it's possible for gdebi to do it, I thought there might be someone who'd be able to point me to some documentation for nautilus API or reflecting gdebi methods in python.

Answer (score 0):

Apt can do it. Apt will figure out dependencies, too.

```
sudo apt install /path/to/downloaded.deb
```

Or dpkg can do it. Dpkg won't figure out dependencies.

```
sudo dpkg --install /path/to/downloaded.deb
```